# How to get boolean index array for pandas DataFrame where obs != last_obs?

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a DataFrame where there is a column we can call 'X.'

So something like 'print(df.X)' would yield some integers somewhere between -10,000 and 10,000. For example:

```
ID     X
1      0
2      0
3      1
4      1
       ...
7334   -19
7335   -19
7336   -20
7337   -20
>>>
```

For the example above, I'd like a boolean index I can use to subset the DataFrame where row 3 is equal to True and row 7336 is equal to True, because the value in X changes from the last observation. All others should be False.

Comment: What is the logic behind 'row 3 is equal to True and row 7336 is equal to True'?

Comment: @Dillon - observation != last_observation. so in 3, df.loc[2, "X"] != df.loc[1, "X"]. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use check equality of your series with a shifted version of itself via [`pd.Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html).

Note the first item in the series must be manually set to `False`, if this is a requirement.

```
df['change'] = df['X'] != df['X'].shift()
df['change'].iat[0] = False

print(df)

     ID   X change
0     1   0  False
1     2   0  False
2     3   1   True
3     4   1  False
4  7334 -19   True
5  7335 -19  False
6  7336 -20   True
7  7337 -20  False
```